# Is there a memory overhead associated with heap memory allocations (eg markers in the heap)?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, memory-management, heap-memory

Thinking in particular of C++ on Windows using a recent Visual Studio C++ compiler, I am wondering about the *heap* implementation:

Assuming that I'm using the release compiler, and I'm not concerned with memory fragmentation/packing issues, is there a memory overhead associated with allocating memory on the *heap*?  If so, roughly how many bytes per allocation might this be?
Would it be larger in `64-bit` code than `32-bit`?

I don't really know a lot about modern *heap* implementations, but am wondering whether there are markers written into the *heap* with each allocation, or whether some kind of table is maintained (like a file allocation table).

On a related point (because I'm primarily thinking about standard-library features like 'map'), does the Microsoft standard-library implementation ever use its own allocator (for things like tree nodes) in order to optimize *heap* usage?

Comment: Typically when you allocate arrays, some bytes are stored at the beginning with the size allocated for future deletes. For large allocations, the overhead is close to none. If you allocate, say, 4 bytes at a time, it can very well double the memory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.

Every block of memory allocated will have a constant overhead of a "header", as well as a small variable part (typically at the end). Exactly how much that is depends on the exact C runtime library used. In the past, I've experimentally found it to be around 32-64 bytes per allocation. The variable part is to cope with alignment - each block of memory will be aligned to some nice even 2^n base-address - typically 8 or 16 bytes.

I'm not familiar with how the internal design of `std::map` or similar works, but I very much doubt they have special optimisations there.

You can quite easily test the overhead by:

```
char *a, *b;

a = new char;
b = new char;

ptrdiff_t diff = a - b;

cout << "a=" << a << " b=" << b << " diff=" << diff;
```

[Note to the pedants, which is probably most of the regulars here, the above a-b expression invokes undefined behaviour, since subtracting the address of one piece of allocated and the address of another, is undefined behaviour. This is to cope with machines that don't have linear memory addresses, e.g. segmented memory or "different types of data is stored in locations based on their type". The above should definitely work on any x86-based OS that doesn't use a segmented memory model with multiple data segments in for the heap - which means it works for Windows and Linux in 32- and 64-bit mode for sure].

You may want to run it with varying types - just bear in mind that the diff is in "number of the type, so if you make it `int *a, *b` will be in "four bytes units". You could make a `reinterpret_cast<char*>(a) - reinterpret_cast<char *>(b);`

[diff may be negative, and if you run this in a loop (without deleting `a` and `b`), you may find sudden jumps where one large section of memory is exhausted, and the runtime library allocated another large block]

Comment: I've added a comment to that effect. If you have a suggestion for a better way to determine the distance between two independent allocations, feel free to suggets.

Comment: No no, I wasn't implying that, just pointing something out. For proving stuff like this, sometimes you resort to UB, no problem there :)

Comment: Ah, edited my comment while you were providing an answer to the original comment. Sorry for any other readers... ;)

Comment: Thanks @Mats.  I hadn't considered a heap allocator to be so predictable that in most cases the difference between successive (equal sized) allocations gives a reliable indication of memory overhead.  I might give that a try.

Comment: As long as you don't run it in multiple threads, or have call some function that allocates on the heap in between your calls to new, it should be fine. Of course, this applies to a heap that uses one large chunk of memory to provide different allocations... It is possible to have allocators that don't do that. Also, if by the time you get to this code, you've already done a bunch of alloc/free calls to the underlying heap, it may reuse memory blocks that come from those calls to free them - which may of course be out of order.

Comment: *"If you have a suggestion for a better way to determine the distance between two independent allocations, feel free to suggets"* I know this post is pretty old, but you could cast the pointers to `std::uintptr_t` (This is one of the cases, where I prefer the c-style casts)

Comment: @MikeMB: Uhm, yeah, but the REASON it is UB isn't that "it will explode and cause WW III to start", but that "the actual result is undefined" - this is because, for example, a segmented memory system, wouldn't have a well-defined way to determine the distance in bytes between two places that are in different segments (x86 protected mode segmentations do not have a direct relationship between the segment and the base-address of the segment, the base-address is in the descriptor table, which is unavailable to the user-mode code).

Comment: (cont'd). So in such a system, `uintptr_t ai = (uintptr_t)a; uintptr_t bi = (uintptr_t)b;` would simply show something like 32 GB difference, since `segA` and `segB` is 8 apart, and stored in the upper half of a `uintptr_t`, and zero is stored in the lower `uintptr_t`. The same effect could be found in a GPU-based system which has "local" and "global" memory segments, for example. You can't, then, meaningfully take the difference between pointers in with different address space (segment), even if you can make them into integers. [And using `reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(a)` would be my choice].

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Maybe I missunderstand you, but: If you are on a platform with segmented memory, then you won't get a reliable answer anyway (regardless of whether you cast the pointers to `char*` or `uintptr_t`). However, when you are on a system with flat memory space, then the version with `char*` is still undefined behavior, whereas `uintptr_t` gives you a welldefined answer.

Comment: Now, traditionally you could say. Construct X was specified as UB, because on platfomr Z you cold not implement a meaningful / consistent behavior, but on all other platforms that should not be a problem. However, compiler become more and more agressive in optimizing based on UB. E.g. if the compiler can prove that a piece of code dereferences a nullptr it will just mark it as non-reachable. Who knows what future compiler will do, when they can prove that you are comparing unrelated pointers (which is pretty easy,when you get them directly from malloc).

Comment: That would of course be rather obvious in this case. I'm not sure what answer the compiler makes up if you print the difference from an UB subtract, but I'd expect that it's obvious. And probably wouldn't happen unless you enable at least some level of optimisation...

Comment: "Note to the pedants, which is probably most of the regulars here" this made me smile a little ;)

Answer (score 4):

Visual C++ embeds control information (links/sizes and possibly some checksums) near the boundaries of allocated buffers. That also helps to catch some buffer overflows during memory allocation and deallocation.

On top of that you should remember that `malloc()` needs to return pointers suitably aligned for all fundamental types (`char`, `int`, `long long`, `double`, `void*`, `void(*)()`) and that alignment is typically of the size of the largest type, so it could be 8 or even 16 bytes. If you allocate a single byte, 7 to 15 bytes can be lost to alignment only. I'm not sure if `operator new` has the same behavior, but it may very well be the case.

This should give you an idea. The precise memory waste can only be determined from the documentation (if any) or testing. The language standard does not define it in any terms.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. All practical dynamic memory allocators have a minimal **granularity**<sup>1</sup>. For example, if the granularity is 16 bytes and you request only 1 byte, the whole 16 bytes is allocated nonetheless. If you ask for 17 bytes, a block whose size is 32 bytes is allocated etc...

There is also a (related) issue of alignment.<sup>2</sup>

Quite a few allocators seem to be a combination of a size map and free lists - they split potential allocation sizes to "buckets" and keep a separate free list for each of them. Take a look at [Doug Lea's malloc](http://g.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html). There are many other allocation techniques with various tradeoffs but that goes beyond the scope here...

---

*<sup>1</sup> Typically 8 or 16 bytes. If the allocator uses a free list then it must encode two pointers inside every free slot, so a free slot cannot be smaller than 8 bytes (on 32-bit) or 16 byte (on 16-bit). For example, if allocator tried to split a 8-byte slot to satisfy a 4-byte request, the remaining 4 bytes would not have enough room to encode the free list pointers.*

*<sup>2</sup> For example, if the `long long` on your platform is 8 bytes, then even if the allocator's internal data structures can handle blocks smaller than that, actually allocating the smaller block might push the next 8-byte allocation to an unaligned memory address.*

Comment: Thanks for the information & malloc link, @Branko, that appears to be a very good basic introduction to heap management design.