# C++ objects memory consumption

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, new-operator

First of all: this question is not about "how to use delete operator", it is about "why many class objects of small size consumes lots of memory". Let's say we have this code:

```
class Foo
{

};

void FooTest()
{
    int sizeOfFoo = sizeof(Foo);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
        new Foo();
}
```

Size of empty class Foo is 1 byte, but when the code is executed it consumes about 600Mb memory. How is that?

**UPDATE.** I've tested this on Win10 x64 in Visual Studio 2010. Memory usage from OS task manager.

Comment: Are you running in debug mode?

Comment: No, it's release in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Memory allocations have overhead. How much is up to the implementation.

Comment: Good read : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15881440/1870760 regarding memory overhead

Comment: Yeah what the other commenter said is probably what is happening, this isn't the same as saying something like new Foo[10000000]; which would work more as you expected I'd imagine.

Comment: @JonathanPotter, can you be more specific?

Comment: @AlekDepler Some overhead for example is the small amount of data the allocation system uses to keep track of how many bytes were allocated so only the pointer needs to be passed to delete rather than the pointer and the size.

Comment: In C++ you want to avoid allocating small objects individually.

Comment: I just tested this on VS 2015 Win 7 x64 and my application only uses a mere 160 MB in release. The `malloc` implementation in 2010 just isn't as good I assume.

Comment: Try changing your class to have a size of 4, 8 & 16 (add fields...). measure the usage then, and see how it reacts to these changes.

Comment: Consider adapting @lemondrop 's comment about allocating a million `Foo`s and using those million `Foo`s as a pool. When you need a `Foo`, take one from the pool.

Comment: Aside from alignment and array-size-storage overhead, allocating memory   requires manipulating a data structure that represents where all the allocations are (so that they can be efficiently freed later on). Think about it -- the user can allocate many objects on the heap, then deallocate a few in the middle. There needs to be some structure tracking that those middle bytes are now free. And that structure takes memory too (albeit not too much in clever implementations).

Comment: How do you measure the 600 Mb ?  Process statistics from OS or memory debugging tools monitoring allocations ?

Comment: @Christophe, it's Win10 x64, Task Manager

Comment: [Process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062.aspx) has the program consuming 160 MB under VS2010 on Win 10, but about twice that if run under the debugger. No surprise that. Debugger will add it's own memory tracking.

Comment: I'm under the impression you're still running in debug, it's all 160 for us on x64 systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ heap manager has 4 different "modes" in which it reserves less or more space around an object. These are

1. Release mode, running normally
2. Release mode, running under the debugger
3. Debug mode, running normally
4. Debug mode, running under the debugger

The additional memory is used for no mans land (0xFDFDFDFD), alignment to 16 byte boundaries (0xBAADF00D), heap management etc.

I suggest reading [this post](http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html) and looking at the 4 scenarios in a debugger, opening the raw memory view. You'll learn a lot. For case 1 and 3, insert a pause where you can attach the debugger to the running process, while in case 2 and 4 you should run the debugger first and then start the executable from there.

I used to demonstrate how the C++ heap works when explaining the buffer overrun. Here's a demo program you can use, not perfect, but maybe useful:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
void SimpleBufferOverrunDemo( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] ) ;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    SimpleBufferOverrunDemo(argc, argv);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}

void SimpleBufferOverrunDemo( int argc, _TCHAR* argv[] ) 
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        std::cout << "You have to provide an argument!\n";
        return;
    }

    // Allocate 5 bytes
    byte* overrunBuffer = new byte[5];

    // Demo 1: How does the memory look after delete? Uncomment the following to demonstrate
    //delete [] overrunBuffer; //0xfeeefeee in debug mode.
    //DebugBreak();

    // Demo 2: Comment Demo 1 again. 
    // Provide a 5 byte sequence as argument
    // Attach with WinDbg and examine the overrunBuffer.

    // 2.1. How many heaps do we have?
    // !heap -s

    // 2.2. How to find the heap block and how large is it?
    // !heap -x [searchAddress]
    // !heap -i [blockAddress] -> Wow 72 bytes block size for 5 allocated bytes!

    // 2.3. Show that _HEAP_ENTRY does not work any more.

    // Demo 3: Write behind the 5 allocated bytes.
    // Provide more than 5 bytes as argument, depending on how what you want to destroy
    // 3.1 Write into the no mans land.
    // 3.2 Write into the guard bytes.
    // 3.3 Write into the meta data section of the following heap block! -> When does it crash?

    std::wstring arg = argv[1];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arg.size(); i++)
    {
        overrunBuffer[i] = (byte)arg[i];
    }

    // Crash happens not where it was caused(!) This is important!
    std::cout << "Now we do a plenty of other work ...";
    ::Sleep(5000);

    delete[] overrunBuffer;

    // Demo 4: Demonstrate page heap / application verifier!
}
```

Comment: I see now. It's really different memory values for different modes for my example: from 150mb in release mode without debugger up to 600mb in debug mode under debugger. Strange world.

Comment: @AlekDepler: the additional memory provides additional benefits for debugging. See the updated answer for a demo program of a buffer overrun.

Comment: @AlekDepler: I hope you accidentally flipped the values. Release mode should need less memory.

Comment: Yes, I flipped them ) So is it impossible to reduce memory consumption less then 150mb for my example?

Comment: @AlekDepler: as mentioned by Amit, an array should help, since that makes only 1 big allocation + 1 overhead instead of many small allocations + many overheads. Be aware that this does not scale unlimited. You may run into problems where you have enough memory in total, but not as one big free block (which an array needs). That's called "memory fragmentation" then. Try 1800 allocations of a 1MB byte[] versus a single 1800MB byte[] allocation. But that's crazy advanced stuff you hopefully don't need to care about.

Answer (score 3):

Class `Foo` might be 1 byte in size, but since you allocate many `Foo`s individually, they can (and probably do) get allocated on some byte aligned addresses and due to fragmentation consume more memory than you expected.

Additionally, there's the memory used by the internal memory management system.

Comment: still 16b*10,000,000 = 160Mb (when 16b aligned chunks are allocated) and even if 32b are actually allocated (16b for memory management), we still 'only' reach 320Mb.

Comment: @Walter - and that's some part of the answer, is there anything incorrect about this?

Comment: Well, it doesn't explain the 600Mb but only (up to) 320Mb -- so what abotu the remaining memory?

Comment: @Walter, good point. I'm also interested in where is other memory used.

Comment: As I noted (as well as some did in the comments), there are other "hidden" overhead memory allocations taking place.

Comment: @AlekDepler: How are you measuring memory usage? Maybe 512MB are allocated upfront before main even runs, did you rule this out? Maybe 600MB are allocated by the runtime from the system to make further allocations quicker, but not all of this memory is actually consumed by your programs objects (i.e., you could allocate more objects and memory usage wouldn't rise). You need to be much more specific with how you're measuring things and what your runtime is to be able to actually find where this memory is going.

Comment: @Amit Yes, I take this already into account: 16Mb per allocation just to store the amount of memory allocated at the address. This is more than needed, but alignment requirements again may bump this up to 16b. You still fail to explain the 600Mb quantitatively.

Comment: Only getting a 160 MB use here.

Comment: Yeah I am getting 160 as well. As expected from what a heap profile shows the exact amount of memory actually allocated is 10 million bytes so the rest is the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that the memory consumed by a process from the OS point of view is not only related to the objects that are allocated in your code.

It's something that is heavily implementation dependent, but in general, for performance reasons, memory allocation is rarely passed one to one to the OS, but [pooled via the management](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kftdy56f.aspx) of the free store.  The general principle is as follows:

- At startup of the program, your C++ implementation will allocate some initial space for the free store and the heap.
- When this memory is consumed, and new memory is needed, the memory management will request larger chunks to the OS and make these available in the free store.
- It is possible that the size of chunks requested from OS could adapt themselves to the allocation patterns.

So from the 600MB viewed in the task manager, it is possible that only a small part is effectively allocated to your objects, and a bigger part is in fact still free and available in the free store.

This being said, the consumed memory will be larger than size x number of objects:  for each allocated object, the memory management functions have to manage some additional information (like the size of the allocated object).  SImilarly, the free memory pool also requires pointer (generally a linked list) to keep track of the free blocks if these are not contiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting post about Windows.

For comparison, on Ubuntu 15.10(64):

```
int t407(void)
{
   std::cout << "\nsizeof(Foo): " << sizeof(Foo) << std::endl;

   std::cout << "\nsizeof(Foo*): " << sizeof(Foo*) << std::endl;

   std::vector<Foo>  fooVec;
   fooVec.reserve(10000000);
   for (size_t i=0; i<10000000; ++i)
   {
      Foo t;
      fooVec.push_back(t);
   }
   std::cout << "\nfooVec.size(): " << fooVec.size() 
             << " elements" << std::endl
             << "fooVec.size() * sizeof(Foo): " 
             << fooVec.size() * sizeof(Foo) << " bytes" << std::endl
             << "sizeof(fooVec): " << sizeof(fooVec) 
             << " bytes (on stack)" << std::endl;

   return(0);
}
```

With output:

```
 sizeof(Foo): 1

 sizeof(Foo*): 8

 fooVec.size(): 10000000 elements 
 fooVec.size() * sizeof(Foo): 10000000 bytes
 sizeof(fooVec): 24 bytes (on stack)
```

Comment: Try without vector and watch for process memory, not variables.