# Examine memory usage of vector<T>

Tags: c++, windows, memory, vector

I'm having trouble understanding memory usage of `vector<vector<char>`.

I analyzed physical memory usage with `WorkingSetSize` of current process info. 
I assume this way is right, since analysis of codeforces matches my local result.

To be specific, I want to understand memory usage with following code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
#include <psapi.h>

SIZE_T toKB(SIZE_T b) { return b / 1024; }

SIZE_T initialMemory = 0;
void initMemory() {
  PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
  pmc.cb = sizeof(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS);

  HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
  if (GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc))) {
    initialMemory = pmc.WorkingSetSize;
  }
}
void printMemory() {
  PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS pmc;
  pmc.cb = sizeof(PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS);

  HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
  if (GetProcessMemoryInfo(hProcess, &pmc, sizeof(pmc))) {
    std::cout << toKB(pmc.WorkingSetSize - initialMemory) << "KB" << std::endl;
  }

  CloseHandle(hProcess);
}

int main() {
  int N = 100'000;
  int M = 15;

  printMemory();
  initMemory();
  printMemory(); // 0B

  std::vector<std::vector<int>> vec(N, std::vector<int>(M));
  printMemory(); // Result
}
```

I am using Windows 11 and x64 operating system. 
My g++ is MinGW-w64 x86_64 11.3.0. 
I have run code with g++ no option.

Here is the result of experiment:

```
For vector<vector<char>>
M:  1 ~  8 ->  3956KB
M:  9 ~ 24 ->  5584KB (+1628KB)
M: 25 ~ 40 ->  7140KB (+1556KB)
M: 41 ~ 56 ->  8748KB (+1608KB)

For vector<vector<int>>
M:  1 ~  2 ->  3956KB
M:  3 ~  6 ->  5584KB (+1628KB)
M:  7 ~ 10 ->  7140KB (+1556KB)
M: 11 ~ 14 ->  8748KB (+1608KB)
```

#### What I have guessed

For `vector<vector<char>>` and `N = 10^5`, I tried calculating memory usage.

1. There is `vec`, which is `vector<vector<char>>` object, in stack. This costs 24B.
2. `vec` is pointing to contiguously allocated block in heap. 
   The block consists of N * `vector<char>` object. 
   Since `sizeof(vec[0])` is 24B and `vec.capacity() = 10^5`, this block of `vector<char>` costs 2400KB.
3. Each `vec[i]` is pointing to contiguously allocated block in heap. 
   Each block consists of M * char. 
   Since `sizeof(char)` is 1B and `vec[i].capacity() = M` and there are N blocks in total, total blocks of char cost M * 100KB.

In conclusion, total memory usage should be (2400 + M * 100)KB.

#### Result of experiment

However the result of experiment suggests:

- `vector<char>` with capacity 1~8 uses 16B.
- `vector<char>` with capacity 9~24 uses 32B.

From the result, I assume the memory is working as below:

```
|-----------------| 16B
 ???(8B) 1~8chars

|-----------------||-----------------| 32B
 ???(8B)  8 chars       1~16 chars
```

#### Additional Experiment

Instead of using vector, I tried to reproduce behavior with `new []`.

```cpp
struct Xn {
  int a, b, c; // make sizeof(Xn) == n
};

// Version A (allocating x bytes N times)
Xn *(ary[N]);
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  ary[i] = new Xn;
  *(ary[i]) = Xn{};
}

// Version B (single x * N bytes allocation)
Xn *arr = new Xn[N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
  arr[i] = Xn{};
}
printMemory();
```

Result:

```
Version A
every pointer is 8B
char ~ X8  -> 2372KB (N * 8B + N * 16B)
X12 ~ X24  -> 4000KB (N * 8B + N * 32B)
X28 ~ X40  -> 5556KB (N * 8B + N * 48B)

Version B
new char[N] ->  100KB (N *  1B)
new int[N]  ->  392KB (N *  4B)
new  X8[N]  ->  784KB (N *  8B)
new X12[N]  -> 1176KB (N * 12B)
new X20[N]  -> 1960KB (N * 20B)
new X32[N]  -> 3132KB (N * 32B)
```

I think this result matches my assumtion of memory model.

#### Question

Although there is high chance that my model is wrong at first place, I want to ask

1. What is the mysterious ??? consuming 8B? 
   If there was no ???, 1B ~ 16B will be allocated 16B, also 17B ~ 32B will be allocated 32B. 
   Because of ???, 1B ~ 8B is allocated 16B, then 9B ~ 24B is allocated 32B.
2. Why does the memory allocation seem to partitioned in 16B? 
   Maybe it is because memory alignment? However I thought unit of memory alignment is 4B. 
   So I assume `vector<char>` with M: 9~12 can use only 20B, M: 13~16 can use only 24B and so on. 
   **A**: This is about heap memory allocator and granularity. 
   [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881170/is-there-a-memory-overhead-associated-with-heap-memory-allocations-eg-markers-i/15881440#15881440)

   > if the granularity is 16 bytes and you request only 1 byte, the whole 16 bytes is allocated nonetheless. If you ask for 17 bytes, a block whose size is 32 bytes is allocated etc...
3. Maybe c++ is preallocating more area in case of push_back? 
   If this is the case, how should I optimize memory usage? 
   I want to use run time length N but I will not use push_back. 
   I have found `dynarray` will fit, but it isn't in standard. 
   **A**: No. Allocating x bytes N times manually in "Additional Experiment" still has same problem. 
   So it is not problem with `vector` but with heap allocator. 
   To optimize memory usage, it is better not to dynamically allocate 2d vector or array. 
   Instead, use larger 1d vector with size N * M.

Comment: The `std::vector` is an object usually with fixed size.  It references its data from dynamic memory.  Your data/results may be reflecting this.

Comment: If you didn't use vector at all and wrote your own `vector` class using plain old `new[]` and `delete[]`, you will more than likely see similar results.  This looks more to be a heap manager issue, and not one of `std::vector`.

Comment: The `std::vector` creates space in dynamic memory.  When the contiguous space in dynamic memory is near full, the `std::vector` will reallocate with a larger size.  The reallocation quantity is implementation dependent.

Comment: You should be able to figure out the answer to your question via a simple experiment: allocating 1 byte 100000 times will use up much more memory than a single 100000 byte allocation. And the answer to the question should become obvious once you consider the fact that, in the case of the former, you have a magical ability to free just the right amount of memory by randomly deallocating one of those bytes, and, as if by magic, it is determined that only 1 byte needs to be deallocated, and not 4 or 5. That information must be stored somewhere, doesn't it?

Comment: Each instance of std::vector will use a bit of memory. Then it will dynamically allocate memory on the heap (contiguously) and usually a bit more than what you initially need (it is kind of preparing to let itself grow for when you call methods like push_back). If you know the size of the vector up-front you can use one of the constructors that allocates the number of elements you need (or you can call `reserve`). All in all you really should be reading the documentation here [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: Thanks for the comments :) I will check for heap management.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I thought `std::vector<char>` has size of 24B, so I considered N * `vector<char>` taking 2400KB in data. Also as I specified capacity in constructor. I think reallocation did not happen in my case. I also checked capacity of each `vector<char>` was M after printMemory.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you for guiding me. I have conducted more experiment with your comment. When it comes to `std::vector`, I think size and capacity will act as the information for deallocating. Because vector has pointer, size and capacity, it takes 24 byte to store it. However even after considering 24KB for each vector, there is still missing 8B per block which I cannot understand.

Comment: Please reread my comment. Forget everything about what `std::vector` is or is not, or how many bytes of overhead it is. Actual memory allocation/deallocation occurs at a much lower level, that doesn't know anything about `std::vector` or anything else. Consider that allocating 100000 bytes in one chunk ends up using far less memory than allocating 1 byte a 100000 times, and the fact that deallocating each individual byte correctly deallocates it, and if you used 2 or 4 bytes at a time instead of 1, the right thing will happen too. After pondering what all of that means, you have your answer.